# CPU time value in resource manger is different from CPU time obtained with 'time' command

Tags: time, cpu-usage, cpu-time

I am trying to get the CPU usage time of my Python program using `time python my_code.py`, where the program executes a long deep learning training process. The result of time command is `244m` for user-time and `13.5m` for sys-time (after dividing by the number of cores). However, the CPU time obtained from **Centos 7** resource manager of the running process is only `187.5m` and it's almost identical to the value obtained in `ps` command.

Shouldn't the value of (user-time+sys-time) be the same as the one obtained with the resource manager(or ps command)? If not, why `user+sys = 13.5 + 244 = 257.5m` is much bigger than process CPU time (`187m`)?

Which one represents the CPU time of the process?